# Looping through a Python-3.x List terminates at index 1499 and restarts at index 0 even though the length of the list is 549,000

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

Looping through a Python List terminates at index 1499 and restarts at index 0 even though the length of the list is 549,000. At the end, the looping evaluates only 542,778 items instead of the 549,000 items in the list, and the 542,778 items returned constitute a repetition of the first 1500 items.
Here is the code that I am working with. The file "wikipedia_dataset_flat.xlsx" can be gotten from my google drive link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10n791MolfvIb4PTl6cplfkXxUI-xyPVV/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106195525795358234651&rtpof=true&sd=true:

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
wikipedia = pd.read_excel('E:/My Drive/Data Science/python/test/wikipedia_dataset_flat.xlsx', index_col=0)
page_list=list(wikipedia.page)
wikipedia.info()
len(page_list)
Page_visited=[]
Language=[]
Device=[]
Indexes=[]
i=0
for page in page_list:
    Indexes.append(page_list.index(page))
    num=Indexes[i]+1
    i=i+1
    page_len=len(page)
    print('page ', num,' is: ',page,' of length: ',page_len) #print name of page with its position to check if the whole list is evaluated.
    words=page.split('_')
    word_len=len(words)
    #print(words)
    for word in words:
        if 'wikipedia' in word:
            pos=words.index(word)
            page_sep=''
            lang=''
            access=''
            agent=''
            for a in range(word_len):
                wrd=words[a]
                if a<pos:
                    if len(page_sep)==0:
                        page_sep=wrd
                    else:
                        page_sep=page_sep+'_'+wrd
            wiki=words[pos]
            lang=wiki[:2]
            access=words[pos+1]+'_'+words[pos+2]
            Page_visited.append(page_sep)
            Language.append(lang)
            Device.append(access)            
        elif word==words[word_len-1] and len(lang)==0:
            access=np.nan
            lang=np.nan
            agent=np.nan
            page_set=np.nan
            Page_visited.append(page_sep)
            Language.append(lang)
            Device.append(access)
print('Total no. of pages in the list Page_list: ',len(page_list))
print('Length of list Page_visited: ',len(Page_visited))
print('Length of list Language: ',len(Language))
print('Length of list Devices: ',len(Device))
#print(Indexes)
print('Length of list Indexes: ',len(Indexes))
dict_wiki={'Page_visited':Page_visited,'Language':Language,'Device':Device}   
#print(dict_wiki)
p_l_a=pd.DataFrame(dict_wiki)
wiki_views=pd.concat([wikipedia,p_l_a],axis=1,join='inner')
```

'''
Please help.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n1AA.png)

Here is the output. Note that after page 1500, the following page is page 1.
[image showing output of list of items in the page_list list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8McB.png)

Comment: It is poor practice using a `for loop` in a `pandas dataframe` (especially a large one). You should use a `vectorized` method.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am currently starting out learning python and pandas.

Comment: that's okay chief.  we all start from somewhere...    part of the learning process !!

Comment: please provide a link to the dataset (the excel file) or alternatively an example dataframe.